# Can Dataframe.style be applied only to particular row of the dataframe

Tags: css, python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

i have a dataframe as shown in the image.
[Dataframe image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeKbf.png)  the last row of the dataframe is the sum of the values in that column. Now looking for applying style or formatting (like want to highlight a value which is less than 40 in that row) only to that last row. Is it possible to do so?

Tried some options like dataframe.style but it neither applied style nor throws any error.
Please help me with other alternatives.

Comment: Hi. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)